# Why instead of function compiler sees a 'unsigned int'?

Tags: c

I really don't understand, what's the problem with my code. I done very similar before and no compilation errors appeared. I have a code:

```
double shape(int i,double x)
{
    double fun,h,L;
    int n;
    n=100;
    L=1.0;
    h=L/n;
    x=x-i*h;
    x=fabs(x);
    if(x<=h)
    fun=(1.0-x/h);
    else
    fun=0.0;
    return fun;
}

void main()
{
    int N=101;
    double O,F,h;
    h=0.001;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        F=h*(i+1);
        O=shape(i,F);
    }
}
```

And on the last line it gives me compilation errors:
Error: found 'unsigned int' expected a double
Warning: missing prototype.
WHY?

Comment: put semicolon to your 2 statements h=0.001; and O=shape(i,F);

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a semicolon there.

Comment: You must learn to indent your code.

Comment: No you don't have a semi colon there. Look at the question. Or are you posting fake code. Don't! Please post your actual code. Use copy/paste. Do not ever post fake code. And post all of your code. It is currently incomplete.

Comment: It works for me if it have those 2 semicolon. You are missing end bracket for main function

Comment: I just made a mistake when pasting the code here. Sorry.

Comment: Well you still need to fix it. It is still broken. Please fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: You have a missing #include, a missing close curly brace, a `void main()` and an unused variable. Fix these, [and it will compile](http://ideone.com/HYPLJH) (not saying "it will work" though).

Answer (score 0):

> Error: found 'unsigned int' expected a double Warning: missing prototype.

This indicates that you are calling a function that does not have a prototype. When that happens your compiler assumes a default return value type of `unsigned int`. The solution is to add the missing prototype.

The code that you have posted is incomplete. It would seem that the call to `shape` is triggering the error. But the `shape` is clearly defined. Most likely in the real code `shape` is either in a different file, or is first declared below `main`.

You should be configuring your compiler so that it does not accept function calls if the function has not been declared. The fact that the C language accepts such things dates back to the very early days of the language. You should configure your compiler to disallow these ancient and bad practises.

Your program is going to fail at runtime when you do get it to compile. You will overflow `F` in the loop in `main`.

Finally, your `main` function is declared incorrectly. It should be

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: AAAAAAH! I found the error!! I had also a unsigned variable 'shape' in my code!!! Stupid me! Sorry and THANK YOU so much for help!

Comment: I urge you next time to post your real code rather than fake code.

Comment: So what? Strip out all the bits that we don't need and post verbatim a complete program that illustrates the problem. Do you think that your approach of posting fabricated fake code is the way to go?